# What is a good gc tuning strategy for gc output that I have?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

This is the output after running for around 10 minutes.

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 7040K, used 0K [0x24060000, 0x247c0000, 0x26790000)
  eden space 6528K, 0% used [0x24060000,0x24060000,0x246c0000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x246c0000,0x246c0000,0x24740000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x24740000,0x24740000,0x247c0000)
 ParOldGen       total 48896K, used 43303K [0x06990000, 0x09950000, 0x24060000)
  object space 48896K, 88% used [0x06990000,0x093d9d80,0x09950000)
 PSPermGen       total 12288K, used 3737K [0x02990000, 0x03590000, 0x06990000)
  object space 12288K, 30% used [0x02990000,0x02d366c0,0x03590000)
[GC [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(7040K)] 43303K->43303K(55936K), 0.0005129 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
[Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(7040K)] [ParOldGen: 43303K->43303K(48896K)] 43303K->43303K(55936K) [PSPermGen: 3737K->3737K(12288K)], 0.1964557 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My advice is don’t try to tune GC.
JVM will handle it.

Comment: problem is the application runs out of memory after running for a while. I think it has to do with gc. In my unit test if I call gc explicitly I recover the allocated mem but this does not happen when the full app is running. so I wanted to know how to tune gc

Comment: Please provide a bit more information, like JVM Version, Hardware, JVM Arguments

Comment: Calling GC explicitly shouldn't do anything if you're using a modern GC. If possible, try to get a heap dump too to see what objects are filling the memory.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the heap size (-Xmx)? The gc output shows you kept everything you allocated in use (referenced), nothing was collected. And if that is not what you intended, then you have a memory leak. In either case, gc tuning will not help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using something like JConsole (JDK 1.5+) or jVisualVM (JDK1.6). A single output of printgc is not enough to give a good recommendation.

There are usually two issues: You create too many new Objects, the New Generations fills up quickly and thus the gc moves all those objects to the Survivor Space or even Perm Generation. If this is what happens (they get deleted with the next full gc, which takes longer), I'd recommend to increase the Young/New generation. (-XX:NewSize). This allows the Objects to get unreferenced and deleted by a regular gc.

If you do have many long lived objects, I'd check if that is really necessary. This might mean you have to change code.

Keep in mind, that a large heap takes longer to gc compared to a small heap.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But in the output I notice that the current Young generation space is not utilized at all..so am not sure how increasing this will help. I will check out the other tools you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of memory the problem is not GC, the problem is that you are using too many objects and not releasing them.

The last time I worried about Java's GC was in 1998.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with too many **large** objects being created (and not released) from your application? Dont know the Java GC really, but coming from .NET, large objects are placed on a seperate large object heap which is not compacted by the GC. In an application, utilizing a busy allocation pattern, this could lead to fragmentation on the LOB -> which in turn often causes those nasty OutOfMemory (OOM) exceptions. 
Moreover, LOB collections are always generation 2 collections. This means, they are costly! 
So, the clean solution would be to implement a pooling. Implement a disposal pattern for your large objects and make sure, they are released to the pool after use. Reuse them for new objects by reclaiming them from the pool. 
Once again, this does only apply, if you have too many large allocations. So you may clear this out first.